# Fluentd unable to parse Json logs coming from node pm2 server

Tags: json, elasticsearch, pm2, fluentd

I am using fluentd, Elasticsearch and Grafana stack for logging and monitoring setup. I am tailing the logs(in JSON format) coming from NodeJS container/pod deployed in EKS cluster and dumping into Elasticsearch.

**Problem**
The log format coming in stdout from node(deployed using pm2 web server) is not accurate json
for example:

```
10:37:01 0|server | {"timestamp":"*","level":"*","label":"*","user":"*","message":"*","RequestMethod":"*","RequestPath":"*","StatusCode":*,"MachineName":"V","EnvironmentName":"*","Appplication":"*","CorrelationId":"*"}
```

As you can see above that unnecessary data  `10:37:01 0|server |` is coming outside json {} so as a result while parsing the logs using filter directive its throwing the error and saying "pattern not matched " error

**Goal**
My logs should be fetched from stdout via fluentd and dumped into Elasticsearch hence I need to fix the logs structure just to make sure my logs should look like below:

```
{"timestamp":"*","level":"*","label":"*","user":"*","message":"*","RequestMethod":"*","RequestPath":"*","StatusCode":*,"MachineName":"V","EnvironmentName":"*","Appplication":"*","CorrelationId":"*"}
```

Which means no data `10:37:01 0|server |` coming outside Json {} body. FYI I also checked at the pm2 server whether if we can remove this entry in the logs but couldn't find anything on it.
Any methods that could fix my problem will be great.

Comment: Anyone Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried the `--raw` flag ? https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/